# vncserver don't work by no error in raspberry

Tags: linux, vnc

I have one raspberry zero which settled before correctly and can connect to it by LMDE Linux, but after changing the Linux ti Ubuntu i have problem in working by ti and asked here:

**[Ubuntu WiFi internet connection lost after connecting to raspberry Zero by USB port](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220254/ubuntu-wifi-internet-connection-lost-after-connecting-to-raspberry-zero-by-usb-p)**

And now when i have connected to the raspberry and run `vncserver` command i get this output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ vncserver
VNC(R) Server 6.4.0 (r39899) ARMv6 (Dec 7 2018 12:34:40)
Copyright (C) 2002-2018 RealVNC Ltd.
RealVNC and VNC are trademarks of RealVNC Ltd and are protected by trademark
registrations and/or pending trademark applications in the European Union,
United States of America and other jurisdictions.
Protected by UK patent 2481870; US patent 8760366; EU patent 2652951.
See https://www.realvnc.com for information on VNC.
For third party acknowledgements see:
https://www.realvnc.com/docs/6/foss.html
OS: Raspbian GNU/Linux 9, Linux 4.19.50+, armv6l

On some distributions (in particular Red Hat), you may get a better experience
by running vncserver-virtual in conjunction with the system Xorg server, rather
than the old version built-in to Xvnc. More desktop environments and
applications will likely be compatible. For more information on this alternative
implementation, please see: https://www.realvnc.com/doclink/kb-546

Running applications in /etc/vnc/xstartup

VNC Server catchphrase: "Dexter sensor warning. Xray omega airport."
             signature: 76-39-1a-c4-21-7b-c8-01

Log file is /home/pi/.vnc/raspberrypi:1.log
New desktop is raspberrypi:1 (192.168.7.2:1)
```

shown below:
[image]

also AngryIp find it and ping answering like this:

[image]

```
PING 192.168.7.2 (192.168.7.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.7.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.317 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.7.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.371 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.7.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.446 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.7.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.454 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.7.2: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.447 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.7.2: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.562 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.7.2: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.344 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.7.2: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.420 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.7.2: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=0.388 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.7.2: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=0.352 ms
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It have been solved by using [**realvnc**](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/) software in Ubuntu, but i don't know why don't working now by others VNC software base in Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.